# Moving folders used wrong syntax and lost them

Tags: ls, rename, dot-files

I thought I was being smart trying to move a folder to one level up by going:

```
mv folder .newfolder
```

and neglecting to even put:

```
mv folder .newfolder/folder
```

and anyway it didn't put up an error but the folders have vanished.

Where could they be I wonder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mv folder to .newfolder` - `.mvfolder`, the dot in front hides the files.

Try `ls -la` - its on the same level as your `folder`, probably.